# Xcode 7.0.1, iOS 9 App Transport Security

Tags: admob, ios9, xcode7, nsapptransportsecurity

I saw in the AdMob site that it states to ensure that ads are not impacted by ATS, I have to add some exception into info.plist file

But I look at info.plist file and I see no NSAppTransportSecurity option.

It also states "The following log message appears when a non-ATS compliant app attempts to serve an add via HTTP on iOS9:

"App Transport Security has blocked a cleartext HTTP (http://)resource load since it is insecure.Temporary exceptions can be configured via your app's info.plist file."

I never receive above message in debug area, does it mean I don't have to add any NSAppTransportSecurity?

Answer (score 0):

You should add the required keys to your info.plist now. You may not see the error message right away, due to you not actively targeting iOS 9 only, or perhaps the library is preventing the messages in some way.

If you (or the library) are making calls over `http`, you will need to tell the system to allow arbitrary loads. Add this to your `info.plist`:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```

If you're making calls over `https`, but not using a strong enough encryption, you can add a domain exception like this:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
    <dict>
        <key>whatever.com</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
            <true/>                
            <key>NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
            <false/>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

Comment: I've seen the first code that you wrote, but how do I added it and where in info.plist? I don't see a  NSAppTransportSecurity option

What do you mean by making calls over http link? I don't understand that?

I have an iOS game and the only thing that sends you to a website is my Facebook/Twitter share button that I implemented with SLComposeViewController

Comment: You can add options to the `info.plist` even if you don't see it right away. You can even right click the `info.plist` file and hit `Open as Source Code` to see the XML. Then just add the code above to the bottom (above the final `</dict>`). By 'making a call over HTTP', I mean you (or most likely the library) is making API requests over HTTP.

Comment: @HELLO did this help?

Comment: Not only did it not help, it doesn't work. When I put in the 1st code you wrote then in plist's property list: Bundle version string, short <-- appears and ViewController Based Status bar disappears because Bundle version string, short takes its place.

Comment: Can you paste your plist here?

Comment: Source code. You could also try adding the keys manual way. Add a new row, set the key to `NSAppTransportSecurity`, make it a Dictionary, add a row to that, set its key to `NSAllowsArbitraryLoads`, make it a `Bool` and set it to `true`.